# tar can't extract the archive - tar: "Failed to set default locale"

Tags: internationalization, tar

I have set `LANG` to **en_GB.utf8**. I received a `tar` archive, which I can list fine with `tar tf FILENAME`, but when I want to extract it with `tar xf FILENAME`, no file is extracted, and I get the error message

```
 tar: Failed to set default locale
```

Therefore I tried a

```
 LANG=C tar tf FILENAME
```

and this managed to extract the tarball. I guess *tar* somehow knows that the archive was created under the C locale, and needs the C-locale to properly create the extracted filenames, but why can't it set this by itself?

Running under zsh on Monterey.

Comment: The official name of the locale you want is `en_GB.UTF-8`, not `en_GB.utf8`.