# Error message about `cal` regarding locale

Tags: internationalization, zsh

MacOS 12.6.5, running zsh:

I just noticed, that when I type

```
 cal
```

I get the error message

```
cal: setlocale: No such file or directory
```

along with the calender to be displayed. Why is this the case?

More details:

- The error message would imply that `cal` tries to execute an external program named *setlocale*, which obviously is not in the PATH. However, I don't expect such an utility to exist anyway; `setlocale` is a C-function, not an external command.
- I verified (by doing a `type -a cal`), that I'm indeed running `/usr/bin/cal`, and not some alias or shell function masking this utility.
- My `LANG` is set to `en_GB.utf8`, and executing a `LANG=C cal` does not produce the error message anymore. The error seems to occur, when `cal`, unable to deal with my LANG setting, tries to set a safe locale, and fails to do so.
- I feel that the problem is somehow related to a similar effect I asked about [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/461449/tar-cant-extract-the-archive-tar-failed-to-set-default-locale), although the error message is different.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem seems to be that the official name of the locale you want is `en_GB.UTF-8`, not `en_GB.utf8`. Try

```
env LANG=en_GB.UTF-8 cal
```

I was curious about why it seemed that `cal` tries to execute an external program named `setlocale`. Here is what I've found.

`cal` in macOS is actually `ncal`. See the source here:
https://opensource.apple.com/source/misc_cmds/misc_cmds-33/ncal/ncal.c.auto.html

The message `cal: setlocale: No such file or directory` comes from this call, right at the start:

```
if (setlocale(LC_ALL, "") == NULL)
    warn("setlocale");
```

So, no, `cal` does not try to execute anything. The error message is misleading.